# Temporarily Disable logging for log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

How can I temporarily disable logging of log4net based on the result of my function? 
example:

```
if (MyCondition)
{
//Stop logging
}
else
{
//go on, log me...
}
```

i tried using these codes:

```
 LogManager.GetRepository().Threshold = LogManager.GetRepository().LevelMap["OFF"];
 LogManager.GetRepository().Threshold = LogManager.GetRepository().LevelMap["ALL"];
```

to try to disable log4net logging, but the results are the same. log4net is still logging.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to set the logging to "OFF" for all loggers at runtime, then switch them back on afterwards.

Some more info can be found here: http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2007/08/22/114900.aspx